# Make <select> options "click" automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Let's say I've got a drop down like this:

```
<div class="selector">
    <select name="perPage">
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm know PHP and Javascript (jQuery) so a solution in either would be just fine. But I've got a `submit` button underneath it, and instead of that, I was wondering if there's a way to click the drop down, pick your value, then have it send that automatically with OUT having to hit a submit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the 'onchange' element of the select:

```
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

This only uses javascript without the need of loading the whole JQuery library - unless you use JQuery for other functions on the site.

Comment: No jQuery needed with this one.

Comment: You sir are brilliant, thanks! The other answers are good, but if I don't HAVE to break open a JS file, i'd rather not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the `change` event using jQuery and submit the parent form automatically. Something like this:

```
$('.selector select[name=perPage]').on('change', function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign an id to to select, e.g. `selectID`, then add jQuery of the form:

```
$('#selectID').change(function(){
    this.form.submit()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name="perPage"]').on('change', submitForm);
```

where submitForm is a function that submits the form.